# Text overflow ellipsis in Listview only on item that actually overflow

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, text, overflow

I have a horizontal ListView which is in the Column in which I want to show ellipsis on the last Text widget, if that list overflow. How I can achieve this? I added  TextOverflow.ellipsis on Text widget but it still doesn't work. So I want for that last item in that horizontal list (Obstetrics & Gynae in this case) to have ... at the end.

```
class Card extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<DoctorData?>(
      future: _bloc.getData(id: id, context: context),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final data = snapshot.data;

          if (data != null) {
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => (),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Image(data: data),
                      const SizedBox(width: 8),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(data.name),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 18,
                              child: ListView.separated(
                                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text(
                                  data.relations[index].code,
                                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                ),
                                separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Text(' · '),
                                itemCount: data.relations.length,
                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 8),
                      const ChevronRightIcon(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        }

        return Container();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try adding width to SizedBox which wraps your ListView.seperated. If you want overflow to appear only when space is not available, add width as Device Width minus some value. For eg SizedBox(height: 18, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 50,...)

Comment: I tried, it's not working, the result is same.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail about what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So I want for this last item in that horizontal list (Obstetrics & Gynae in this case) to have ... at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use ellipsis it should overflow, but in listView it just expands to take space, So you can wrap you subTitle in the sized box.

```
SizedBox(
      width: context.width * 0.9, // we are letting the text to take 90% of screen width
      child: Text(
        data.relations[index].code,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
    );
```

If you have any questions please free to drop it in comments I will try to address those. Thanks

UPDATE:

Here is the UI implemented in the [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=556cbc86781b2b2827a494fb5be60f14).

And [gist link](https://gist.github.com/MohanSaiManthri/556cbc86781b2b2827a494fb5be60f14)

[image: Expanded UI]
[image: Collapsed UI]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. First item then takes all the space. If your context.width is  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width?

Comment: Yes, Lemme build the UI for you

Comment: What, what is Lemme?

Comment: I mean I will try to build the same UI and will share it here

`Lemme -> Let me`

Comment: @Joe does the issue resolved?

Comment: Hmm, no, it's still not working, because you used regular Text widget for subtitle, but I need to use Listview there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246994/discussion-between-mohan-sai-manthri-and-joe).